# Express: Optional trailing slash for top-level path

Tags: node.js, routes, express

**Update:** My question did not accurately convey what I'm trying to achieve. I wish to match `/foo`, `/foo/`, and anything under `/foo/` (e.g. `/foo/asdf/jkl`), not the given paths specifically. The original question follows.

---

I'd like to match the following paths:

```
/foo
/foo/bar
/foo/bar/baz
```

These should work, too:

```
/foo/          ->  /foo
/foo/bar/      ->  /foo/bar
/foo/bar/baz/  ->  /foo/bar/baz
```

I tried the following:

```
app.get('/foo/*', ...);
```

This fails in the `/foo` case, though. I know that I can provide a regular expression rather than a string, but this is surely a common requirement so I'd be surprised to learn that the pattern-matching DSL does not accommodate it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It appears that a regular expression is the way to go:

```
app.get(/^[/]foo(?=$|[/])/, ...);
```

Answer (score 7):

I know this is an old question, but I had the same issue and I came up with this:

```js
app.get(['/foo', '/foo/*'], ...);
```

This will match `/foo`, `/foo/`, and anything under `/foo/...`. I think this is a more readable solution than a regular expression and it communicates clearly what is intended.

Answer (score 5):

<s>If you want to match them in one pattern:</s>

```
app.get('/foo(/bar(/baz)?)?', ...)
```

The default Express behaviour of allowing an optional `/` at the end applies.

**EDIT:** how about this?

```
app.get('/foo/:dummy?*', ...)
```

Comment: I've updated the question. Sorry for my lack of clarity first time around.

Comment: Heh. `/foo/:dummy?*` should do the trick, though it's about as cryptic as the equivalent regular expression. ;)

Comment: Yes, I think it roughly translates to `/foo(/.+?)?(.*)` (plus a check for a trailing slash along the way)

Answer (score 3):

I had this issue as well and I have to agree that the Regular expression works the best, however with a slight improvement:

```
app.get('/foo([/].*)?', ...);
```

This would match:

```
/foo
/foo/
/foo/what/ever/you/put/after
```

The `/foo/:dummy?*` doesn't really take the optional `/` after `foo` into account and `/foo(/:dummy*)?` doesn't really match correctly.

`/foo(/:dummy)?*` kinda works but creates an extra variable as it has both `path` and the `*` in separate variables, which is inexpedient in this case.

So personally I would stick with the Regular expression.

Comment: Could you explain how this is an improvement on `/^[/]foo(?=$|[/])/`?

Comment: @davidchambers `/^[/]foo(?=$|[/])/` doesn't take the rest of the url and send it back a variable. It only matches `/foo` and `/foo/`... Unless I have misunderstood something

Comment: You're misinterpreting the pattern, @Tokimon. It matches strings beginning with `/foo` followed by either nothing (`$`) or a slash (`[/]`). So `'/foo'` and `'/foo/'` are matched but so is `'/foo/bar/baz'`. You're right that the pattern does not capture the rest of the path, but that wasn't a requirement.

Comment: OK yeah... I had to read the expression a few times more to fully understand it. It only checks the first part of the path. Got it :) Then no you are right it is the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Leave off the slash and it should work just fine:

```
app.get('/foo', ...);
```

Comment: This would result in false positives. For example, `/foobar` would match.

Comment: @davidchambers no it won't. By default, Express will match the route suggested by Andrew against both `/foo` and `/foo/` (but nothing else). You can turn off that behaviour with the [strict routing](http://expressjs.com/api.html#app-settings) option, but in your case, Express' default behaviour should work just fine.

Comment: @robertklep You're right. I misread Andrew's suggestion as `/foo*` (which has the problem of /foobar matching erroneously). The problem with `/foo` is that /foo/bar doesn't match. I've summarized [problems with `/foo` and `/foo*`](http://bit.ly/10IhTRL).

Comment: @davidchambers so you want one pattern to match all of the above?

Comment: @robertklep Yes. Ideally one pattern to match /foo, /foo/, and anything under /foo/. At the moment it looks as though I'll need something like `/^[/]foo(?=$|[/])/`. :\

Comment: @davidchambers I think it wasn't clear that you wanted one pattern :) See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the [@davidchambers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/312785/davidchambers) answer's example in regex101.

But I deleted `[]` and add escape `\`, notice that regex option is `gm`(global and multiline).

`app.get(/^[/]foo(?=$|[/])/, ...);`

https://regex101.com/r/q38rvF/1